# Drawing random points in JApplet

Tags: java, random, applet

Real quick question here. In an attempt to generate 20,000 random points, I wrote the following code:

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Points extends JApplet {
    int x, y;
    public void paint (Graphics page) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++);
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random()*200);
            y = (int)(Math.random()*200); 
            page.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
        }
    }

}
```

However, this resulted in only one point being (randomly) drawn. Can someone help me identify my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon just after your `for`. Erase it and your code will work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    x = (int)(Math.random()*200);
    y = (int)(Math.random()*200); 
    page.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
}
```

Further Explanation: When you use the semicolon after a `for` declaration, it will end the `for` statement, resulting in something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
}
x = (int)(Math.random()*200);
//rest of the code...
```

That's why your code display only 1 point.

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks so much, I knew there had to be a syntax error in there somewhere but I just couldn't find it.